# 03 Pontiac Grand Am won't start

Tags: engine, starting, pontiac, grand-am

I was driving the car today oil light came on went 1 mile to store and got oil but was only 1 qt low put it in had about 3 miles to go got one mile when it died again pushed it to the house now it click sounds like starter starts to engage but stops with the click what could be wrong

Comment: If you pushed that thing a mile ... hat's off to you. That will get the quads a screaming!

Answer (score 2):

If the oil light stayed on after adding oil, then it could be your oil pump that had failed.  If so, the the engine may have siezed.  You may be hearing the starter motor attempting to turn the engine over, but not being able to.

Answer (score 0):

Check the charge on the battery. I bet it is dead. You are looking for ~12v or more, but I bet you are down into the 8-9v range.

If your battery shows good, you might have a connectivity issue at the terminals, especially if there is any amount of corrosion on the battery terminals.